# Calling an application (on an aarch64 architecture) gives "No such file or directory"

Tags: 64-bit, architecture, arm64

I have installed M*plus* on Ubuntu 22.04. My architecture is aarch64, when I run the application I get:

`bash: /opt/mplus/8.8/mplus: No such file or directory`

I installed M*plus* using the following commands:

`chmod a+x mplus.bin`
`./mplus.bin LAX_VM /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-arm64/bin/java`

The output of `ls -l /opt/mplus/8.8/`is:
`total 61754`
`drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     3452 Jan  5 16:45 Documentation`  
`drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root     3452 Jan  5 16:45 Examples`
`drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root     3452 Jan  5 19:05 jre`
`-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 63152192 Apr 25  2022 mplus`
`drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     3452 Jan  5 16:47 uninstall`

The output of `file /opt/mplus/8.8/mplus`:

`/opt/mplus/8.8/mplus: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped, too many notes (256)`

Comment: How did you install it and how do you run it?

Comment: I installed it using:
`chmod a+x Mplus.bin
./mplus.bin LAX_VM /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-arm64/bin/java`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this information. It is unreadable in comments.

Comment: Please also add output of `ls -l /opt/mplus/8.8`

Comment: It looks wrong to me. Is it `Mplus.bin` or `mplus.bin`? These are different files.

Comment: And how are you trying to run it? Also please add output of `file /opt/mplus/8.8/mplus`

Comment: I am trying to run it as I do in a x86_64 architecture, calling: `mplus` or `/opt/mplus/8.8/mplus`
I have it installed in other Ubuntu machines, and it runs without problems.

Comment: Output of file /opt/mplus/8.8/mplus added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is stated by `file /opt/mplus/8.8/mplus`, the binary has `x86-64` architecture and can't be run on your platform.

There is no evidence at Mplus web site that they have a Linux version for `aarch64`.

Comment: Is there no alternative? Emulation? Multiarch support?

Comment: AFAIK you can't emulate `amd64` on `aarch64`.